# Adobe Reader disappears, unable to open PDFs

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

I am an volunteer tech-support adviser for my church and other friends. Recently, I have had users report that Adobe Reader has "disappeared" from their computers. This has only happened on Win7 machines using Reader 9 or higher. Suddenly the users cannot open PDFs that they were previously able to view. If we try to run Adobe updates it tells us that a newer version is already on the machine. If we try to download and install the latest version it fails. The only thing that has worked is to do a system restore to the last known date when PDFs were viewable. Has anyone else encountered this and, if so, do you know what is causing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible reasons for this.
1. Virus
2. Software has been corrupted
3. Incompatibility due to some recent change in configuration
4. An update which has made the software incompatible

What you can do is try to uninstall it from control panel and re-install it.

If you can't find it in control panel, go to c:/program files and delete any folder which contains the name 'Adobe'. Then install your adobe reader again.